# Create a new batch .txt file with specified content for every current file in a directory

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, command-line

I have a huge list of files on a cluster and I need to create a .txt file for each "pair". Each pair is specified by `filename_R1.fq.gz` and `filename_R2.fq.gz`. for each pair of R1 and R2 files I need to create a text file that contains:

```
#!/bin/bash

#$ -N align.$i   
#$ -j y        
#$ -l h_rt=4:00:00
#$ -pe omp 12

bowtie2 \
--phred33 \
--fast-local \
-X 1000 \
-p 12 \
-x /usr3/graduate/dhc285/reference_files/21G6 \
-1 $i -2 ${i%_R1.fq.gz}_R2.fq.gz \
| samtools view -bS - > ${i%_R1.fq.gz}.bam
```

Where the `$i` command refers to my filenames. I would also like each file to be named `${i%_R1.fq.gz}.txt`. Thanks!

Comment: For future reference, the [batch-file] tag is exclusively for the Windows scripting language (it's stupid, I know, but that's what the tag says).

Comment: "cluster-computing" ? :D

Comment: Where do you have this list?

Comment: i hate English because of its ambiguity. they may sound like each other, but i think you mean `bash`.

Comment: the files are on a shared computing cluster. I'm sorry for all the errors - I'm very new to this.

Comment: sorry, but you goal is unclear to me. You say ".... create a text file that contains:" and then you post a `bash` script. Are you saying you want to have a `bash` script for each pair of thousands of files? That doesn't make sense. Normally, you'd pass your list of pairs to a script that can take each pair and process them. Maybe making a log file, and or putting processed files in a "done" folder or other ideas, depending on your  ultimate needs. Do you really want to write a bunch of `bash` scripts? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter - yeah its definitely not the most practical route, but the computing cluster I'm using won't accept the qsub command for all of the files so I was told to do it by creating multiple bash scripts because those can run without a problem.

Comment: So you just need an `awk` script that reads your list of files, and has a big `filename=$1;printf("line1\nline2\nline3 with %s for filename\nline4....\n", filename) > filename".txt" ` to "print" out the required contents into a separately named file. Sorry, but don't have the time to write it for you. Good luck.

Comment: Please answer Ignacio's question.  How will you be accessing the list of files in question?  Is the list already in a text file of its own, or do you have to scan through a bunch of directories to compile the list yourself?

Comment: @dg99 Sorry -  the files are all inside one directory on a shared computing cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
sge_jobfile() {
  i="$1"
  cat <<EOF > ${i%_R1.fq.gz}.txt
#!/bin/bash

#$ -N align.$i
#$ -j y
#$ -l h_rt=4:00:00
#$ -pe omp 12

bowtie2 \\
--phred33 \\
--fast-local \\
-X 1000 \\
-p 12 \\
-x /usr3/graduate/dhc285/reference_files/21G6 \\
-1 $i -2 ${i%_R1.fq.gz}_R2.fq.gz \\
| samtools view -bS - > ${i%_R1.fq.gz}.bam
EOF
}
export -f sge_jobfile
parallel sge_jobfile ::: *_R1.fq.gz
```

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to. It can often replace a `for` loop.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

If GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel